# How do I adjust Homepod stereo balance?

Tags: homepod, sound-volume

I have a stereo pair of Homepods set up in a normal Hi-Fi set up; that is I sit between the speakers and the speakers and I are in a triangle.

- music volume is clearly unbalanced - a centre sound is louder on the right speaker.
- I physically swapped the speakers several times to rule out a hardware issue.
- My room is not symmetrical
- I have tinnitus in my left ear so sound should adjust for this disablement.

How do I configure things so that central sounds sound from the middle to me?

I play music either directly from Apple Music on Homepods or select Airplay on my iPad.

Comment: There are no such fine-tuned controls available for the HomePod, as far as I am aware, a failing of Apple's "It Just Works" philosophy.

Comment: Just curious, does your tinnitus cause traditional stereo speakers to sound unbalanced? I'm wondering whether the core problem is "the homepod's automatic room layout correction completely screwed up" versus "Apple neglected to include an important accessibility setting" (which, to be clear, is no less of a fail, especially given Apple's purported commitment to accessibility).

Comment: In this case the former - although appears to be better now. My tinnitus probably does need louder sound to one side but is a lesser problem for me but for general accessibility as you say rather a anti disability design

Answer (score 1):

Other than moving your speakers around about all you can do is play with the balance and the equalizer to adjust the sound to your liking.  There is a free app named [eqMac](https://eqmac.app) which lets you apply an equalizer to your mac. It also has sensitive settings for the balance. You can adjust the balance to get the appropriate settings for your home pods. Maybe this balance adjuster does a better job than the internal one.

Comment: Ah I am just using homepod with Apple music or perhaps with ipad

Answer (score -1):

On macOS, you need a utility to change this. On the iPad, iPhone or remove the pair and leave the speakers solitary if volume equality is more important than stereo separation.

- At this point you can set the relative volume levels.
- There is no stereo pan control, just different volumes.

[image: AirPlay volume controls for two HomePods on iPadOS]

If you need stereo mapping, keep the HomePods in the stereo pair and add LoopBack processing to help adjust the mix. This also requires a Mac and the software is free to try, but the license is not cheap.  It could be cheaper than some hardware and a stereo setups and if you need or appreciate and can get perfect sound, the value could be there.

- https://www.rogueamoeba.com/support/manuals/loopback/?page=outputchannels

Comment: But then how does the iPad know what goes to left speaker and what to the right when they decode the stereo music file?

Comment: I think you get a mono mix tbh. You’ll need a different system for your needs if that’s a deal breaker. I do not have AirPods Max to test, but AirPods Pro and normal have no stereo mix control.  @mmmmmm

Comment: Yep - I think the best thing is an Airport Extreme into a normal Amp - or possibly an Airplay amp.

Comment: Bingo. Rogue Amoeba AirFoil was the bomb last time I tried Extreme or Express. Maybe their [sound source app would allow stereo pan](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) and it’s cheaper than their loopback product that should work. I’ll add that as an actual answer.